# Where can I place external JAR references of a WAR file other than WEB-INF/lib or WL_HOME/server/lib

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, weblogic, web-deployment

I have 120 Java Projects exported as JAR files in **D:/FC/APP_LIB** folder. Now I developed a Web Service (JAX-WS), to be deployed on Weblogic 12c (12.1.2), which refers to those JAR files. I don't think it will be a good practice to add all the JARs into the **WEB-INF/lib** of the WAR file (and it will continue in all subsequent WARs I develop).

Also, I want to avoid those JARs to be kept in **WL_HOME/server/lib** folder (default reference) as anytime a change is made in any of the Java Projects will require a deployment in **WL_HOME/server/lib**.

Is there any way I can give an external JAR(s) reference in WAR or Weblogic without embedding them into WAR?

Answer (score 0):

You can write (and use) a **separate class loader** to load classes from anywhere.

That being said I suggest putting the jars into each .war file. Disk space and RAM should not be the problem.

- If a central .jar is modified (and a bug is introduced), all web apps will fail.
- You probably test your web app against a specific version of your libraries. If you update a central .jar, you have to re-run the tests for each application.

Generally speaking you will probably run into problems because of **dependencies**.

Comment: Thanks. But the requirement is such that I need to use a separate folder itself (D:/FC/APP_LIB). But the question is how do I refer its JARs as a part of CLASSPATH in WAR.

Answer (score 0):

May you need [Create Shared Java EE Library or Optional Package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/libraries.htm). See more in [Install a Java EE library](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24401/taskhelp/library/DeployLibrary.html) and [Understanding WebLogic Server Application Classloading](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/classloading.html).

Comment: Thanks @Paul. But for that I need to deploy each of my 120 JARs as libraries in Weblogic. Any changes would require re-deployment. This needs to be avoided. I want them to be referred from an external folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the script used to start Weblogic to include the external directory in the server's classpath.  See %DOMAIN_HOME%\bin\setDomainEnv.sh (or .cmd if Windows).